# How to launch an adobe air application from browser

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to launch an Adobe Air Application from the browser? I am developing an application that uses webcam, and when the user enter on my site, I need to start this adobe air application installed on the user computer. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called browser invocation.

[This article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e19) explains how to do it. The main point is that you need to set the `allowBrowserInvocation` value to `true` in the AIR application's descriptor xml and listen for invocation events.

[This post](http://archive.davidtucker.net/2008/01/11/air-tip-6-launching-an-application-from-the-browser/) gives a more concrete example, though it is a tad old.

Answer (score 2):

1.Set `allowBrowserInvocation` as `true` in `app.xml`

2.Register `BrowserInvokeEvent` in completion,

`NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE, onBrowserInvoke);`

3.Then define,

```
protected function onBrowserInvoke(event:BrowserInvokeEvent):void 
{
    argumentsText = event.arguments.toString();
}
```

4.Create Web Application with creation Complete,

```
var airSWFLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
```

5.Add this in click action on your control which launches client AIR app,

```
var appId:String = ""; //Your client app id 
var pubId:String = ""; //client air publisher
var arguments = //define
airSWF.launchApplication(appId, pubId, arguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/726405?start=0&tstart=0) on the Adobe forums links to the overview of launching Air apps from the browser, and the discussion covers some common problems you might encounter.