# Dragging desktop images in a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

Is there any possibility using the drag&drop technology for dragging desktop images onto a flash swf in a HTML document? I would like to be able to load images by dragging a image file from the desktop or file explorer and the traditional way of selecting it clicking the browse button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that in AIR.  See this blog post for a working example and some additional info: http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/how-to-drag-images-from-browsers-and-desktop-to-adobe-ai/

Comment: The question is that I have a website with a .swf file embebed just for uploading images, so adobe air is for desktop applications.

Comment: You can run AIR apps in a browser, too.  Without it, there is no way to do drag and drop from the desktop, unfortunately.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Did you mean to say that "you can run AIR Apps in a browser"?  Can you clarify that statement?

Comment: I meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228761/how-to-launch-an-adobe-air-application-from-browser