# Adobe AIR opening another AIR app

Tags: file, actionscript-3, air, execute

Im working in Flash CC using AIR3 and I prepared two AIR applications. I want to know if it is possible to run the second air app from the first app. Simple as I can when you click in App1 on button it would open new window with App2. Both apps are AIR but they have different stage size.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672021/adobe-air-to-execute-program

Answer (score 1):

I needed to start different AIR desktop applications from a single "Dispatcher" AIR desktop application and I had a hard time to understand how to do it. Trying different solutions didn't work. Finally I found different ways to do it.
The easier way is to use adobe.utils.ProductManager, it was tested on Windows.

Here is the code:

```
import adobe.utils.ProductManager;
private var pm:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");

private function launchMyApplication(myApplicationID:String):void
    {
        pm.launch("-launch " + myApplicationID);
    }
```

About MyApplication:
It is Flex AIR Application and it has a folder META_INF/AIR; there is a file 
application.xml

1. You can find the Application ID in the tag "id"
2. If you forget to set allowBrowserInvocation = true; the Application you are trying to launch will never start.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [Native Process](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html);
2. See how run via url-sheeme: [answer about BrowserInvocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691292/829264);

   - 2.5: [Run with air.swf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-1c6efe05128cca667e7-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cd2)

If possible I prefer second solution - url-sheeme or air.swf.